# Is ServerFault becoming more popular?

Tags: discussion

I'm recently seeing more questions from ServerFault SE people with lower reputation numbers meaning they are new users.

Does this mean that the ServerFault SE is finally catching on out there in webland?

Are there stats/graphs that might be posted to indicate the use and number of new users for Serverfault?

Comment: http://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic earlier in the year we had 125 questions/day now it's 141.

Comment: @Iain is this admin-only? What I get to see is just an abundance of blobs presumably representing all SE sites.

Comment: @syneticon-dj: Not that I'm aware of - did you log in? I only see the pretty blobby stuff if I go incognito.

Comment: Just blobs for me, even when logged in.

Comment: @Iain just as for MadHatter blobs only, even after login. Any non-admin seeing more than this?

Comment: @syneticon-dj: I just noticed on the right hand side of the line beginning `All Technology` there are `list view` and grid `view buttons` so I guess that's it.

Comment: @MadHatter see above.

Comment: Much better; thank you!  But I take it the historical data ("was 125 questions/day") is your own record, not something that page is telling you?

Comment: @MadHatter: Sorry only just found this. The 125 is a data point from some time over the summer.

Comment: Don't worry about the delay, I bet you have a ton of stuff to do on SF besides keep up with my comments!  And that all makes perfect sense now, thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The most accessible one is the Quantcast chart:

http://www.quantcast.com/serverfault.com

Which does show a definite uptick in visits over the year. Our searchability has improved is my guess.

There are some mod-only indicators that show that new-user involvement is increased over the year.